# Ionic button alignment off

Tags: android, iphone, angular, ionic2

my alignment for ion-header has been off as I have no idea why it will be on the different side when I ionic cordova run on android while it was completely ok on iPhone.

[this was on a Samsung phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Srzg4.png)

[this was on an iPhone: this is the outcome that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0tSJ.png)

below are my codes:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar class="myNav">
      <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button menuToggle small color="white">
          <ion-icon name="md-menu" color="black"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title>HOME</ion-title>
      <ion-buttons end>
          <button ion-button icon-only (click)="logOut()">
            <ion-icon name="md-log-out" ></ion-icon>
          </button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Anyone can help me with this ? thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as per material design for Android. You can override it by using utilities `left` instead of `start` in this case.

```
<ion-buttons left>
  <button ion-button menuToggle small color="white">
      <ion-icon name="md-menu" color="black"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  </ion-buttons>
  <ion-title>HOME</ion-title>
```

You can see [this thread](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/nav-bar-with-button-on-left-side/51963) for more info

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
<ion-icon name="icon_name" item-left></ion-icon>
```

That can be used to put the icon in the left side 
and `item-right` to put it in the right side of the menu header